# position:absolute reduces height

Tags: html, css

```css
.header2
{
   background-color:#CDD1CD; 
   padding: 15px 0;
}

.header1 
{
    background-color: #60db60;
 padding: 10px 0;
}
form
{
  position: absolute
  }
```

```html
<div class="headers header1" id="header1">
     <div class="logo"></div>
  <div class="slogan"></div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="headers header2" id="header2">
      <form>
      <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Email or mobile number</td>
     <td>Password</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td><input type="text"></input></td>
      <td><input type="password"></input></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>
      </td>
         <td><a>Forgot your password?</a></td>
      </tr>
   </table>
   </form>
  </div>
```

I tried to add `overflow:hidden` and i am misplacing it i guess. Provide me the best way which floats my form to the right?

```
position: absolute;
right: 0
```

does this. But height problem still exists.

I don't wish to set height or add float.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Provide me the best way which floats my form to the right?

So don't use `position: absolute`, but use actual `float: right` and apply some kind of clearfix (for example, `overflow: auto`) to parent container:

```
.header2 {
    background-color:#CDD1CD;
    padding: 15px 0;
    overflow: auto;
}
form {
    float: right;   
}
```

Check the demo below.

```css
.header2 {
    background-color:#CDD1CD;
    padding: 15px 0;
    overflow: auto;
}
.header1 {
    background-color: #60db60;
    padding: 10px 0;
}
form {
    float: right;   
}
```

```html
<div class="headers header1" id="header1">
    <div class="logo"></div>
    <div class="slogan"></div>
</div>
<div class="headers header2" id="header2">
    <form>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Email or mobile number</td>
                <td>Password</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="text"></input>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="password"></input>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><a>Forgot your password?</a>

                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: `position:absolute and width:100%` to the `.headers` does what i want. Thanks, Will u please tell me why `position:absolute`is harm ?

Comment: Nothing wrong with position absolute. It's just takes out the element from the normal flow, like if it was not there at all, so the parent collapses without explicit height. I wouldn't use it for this task.

Comment: Thanks. One more doubt. I read many SO answers where users suggested not to use `float`. Any opinions?

Comment: Tools are there to be used. No problem with float at all if you know how to use it. In order to avoid confusion just remember to clear floats after you use them, and it will be fine. Floats are very powerful thing once you are familiar with it, so why not to use it - I would say, use and benefit from it. Floats are very important and you can't *not to use* them in CSS/HTML.